# How do you rename the default scene in the iOS SpriteKit template?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm very new to both Swift and iOS development.

I have been working on a game based off Apple's SpriteKit (with GameplayKit integration) template.

All was working fine until I renamed GameScene.swift and GameScene.sks to MapMainScene.swift and MapMainScene.sks. I made sure to change this code in GameViewController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load 'GameScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
    // including entities and graphs.
    if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

        // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
        if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {

            // Copy gameplay related content over to the scene
            sceneNode.entities = scene.entities
            sceneNode.graphs = scene.graphs

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                view.presentScene(sceneNode)

                view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                view.showsFPS = true
                view.showsNodeCount = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load 'MainMapScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
    // including entities and graphs.
    if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "MainMapScene") {

        // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
        if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! MainMapScene? {

            // Copy gameplay related content over to the scene
            sceneNode.entities = scene.entities
            sceneNode.graphs = scene.graphs

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                view.presentScene(sceneNode)

                view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                view.showsFPS = true
                view.showsNodeCount = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also changed the following in `Gamescene.swift`:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    // Some code
}
```

to this in `MainMapScene.swift`:

```
class MainMapScene: SKScene {
    // Some code
}
```

but the app crashes upon launch. The output of the console says:

```
2016-07-21 16:29:35.593592 MyGame[10656:1944648] [User Defaults] CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6080000e5e00> (Domain: kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null)) is waiting for writes to complete so it can determine if new data is available
2016-07-21 16:29:35.603729 MyGame[10656:1944648] [FenceWorkspace] creating a CA fence port (5d13)
2016-07-21 16:29:35.638 MyGame[10656:1944648] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (GameScene) for key (root); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'
*** First throw call stack:
```

So it looks like there is still a reference to `GameScene` somewhere in my project but I have done a project-wide search and there is no `GameScene` anywhere to be found.

I'm sure this is something really straightforwards. Do I need to change an outlet or something in the storyboard editor?? I can reproduce this problem by trying to change the name of `GameScene` in a new project too so I know it's not something specific to my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GameScene` is actually referenced in one more place, and the error coming from `NSKeyedArchiver` should clue you in as to where: it's encoded in the `.sks` file you're loading. You can find it in the "Custom Class" tab of the `.sks` file in Xcode's editor.

[image: Custom Class Tab]

This setting tells `NSKeyedUnarchiver` what class the encoded scene should be when you load the `.sks` file. This should be the last remaining reference to `GameScene`, so this should complete your renaming!

Comment: That was the hidden place. Thanks!

Comment: You saved the day! Thanks!